# Function orthogonal to powers of $1/\left(1+x^2\right)$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration

Does there exist any continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)/(1+x^2)\in L^1(\mathbb R)$, such that $f(0)=1$ and
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{\left(1+x^2\right)^p}dx=0$$ for every $1\leq p\leq 2$?

Comment: Do you assume $f(x)(1+x^2)\in L_1(\mathbb{R})$, or the integral has to be taken as $\displaystyle\lim_{T\to+\infty}\int_{-T}^T$ ?

Comment: doesn't that follows almost immediately from the Stone–Weierstrass approximation theorem (the linear combination of power of $1/(1+x^2)$ form an algebra etc... ) ? (well at least in the case where $f$ is $L^2$).

Comment: @Simon Henry Careful: $p$ ranges over the interval $[1,2]$, not the positive integers.

Comment: Oh thanks ! I had missed that line.

Comment: May be differentiating in $p$ could help? We get something like $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(x)(\log(1+x^2))^k}{(1+x^2)^p}dx = 0$ for $1 < p < 2$ and we could say that polynomials in $\log(1+x^2)$ are dense in some function space?

Comment: (sorry, typo: the question was: is $f(x){\bf /}(1+x^2)\in L_1$ ?)

Comment: @Aleksei Kulikov: this is why I was asking if there are further assumptions on $f$. If the integral is analytic in $p$, it is constant for all $p\ge 1$ etc.

Comment: @PietroMajer: Yes, $f(x)/\left(1+x^2\right)\in L_1$.

Comment: Just to say it one more time, Aleksei's and Pietro's comments combined show that the answer is *no*: We can consider $g=f_e/(1+x^2)\in L^1$ on $[0,\infty)$, with $f_e$ denoting the even part of $f$. The algebra generated by the $(1+x^2)^{-n}$, $n\ge 1$, is uniformly dense in $C_0[0,\infty)$, and $\int g(1+x^2)^{-n}=0$ for all $n\ge 1$ by analyticity in $p$. So $g=0$ (as a distribution initially), but of course this is not possible when $g(0)=1$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling  in the meanwhile I was writing the details below...

Comment: @PietroMajer: Looks good to me, and not the first time I believe you and I are doing things simultaneously here :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think no such function exists. Assuming $\displaystyle{f(x)\over 1+x^2}\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ the integral $\displaystyle\int_\mathbb{R}{f(x)\over (1+x^2)^p}dx$ is analytic wrto $p>1$: indeed, for any $p>1$ and $|t|<p-1$, expanding $(1+x^2)^{t}$ in powers of $t$ we have, by Tonelli's theorem (w.rto the product measure space $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{N}$)

$$\begin{align}\int_\mathbb{R}\sum_m \bigg|{f(x)\over (1+x^2)^p}\big( \log(1+x^2)\big)^m {t^m\over m!}\bigg|dx&=\\=\int_\mathbb{R} {|f(x)|\over (1+x^2)^{p-|t|}}\,dx&\le\int_\mathbb{R} {|f(x)|\over 1+x^2} \,dx<+\infty\end{align}$$
and then by Fubini's
$$\int_\mathbb{R}{f(x)\over (1+x^2)^{p+t}}dx=\sum_m \bigg(\int_\mathbb{R}{f(x)\over (1+x^2)^p}\big( \log(1+x^2)\big)^m\,dx\bigg) {(-t)^m\over m!}, $$
that is the power series expansion for the integral at $p$.

Therefore $\displaystyle\int_\mathbb{R}{f(x)\over (1+x^2)^p}dx=0$ for all $p\ge1$. Next, to simplify a little we may replace $f$ with its even part, and assume equivalently that the integral on $\mathbb{R}_+$ vanishes. Changing variable with $\displaystyle u={1\over 1+x^2}\in[0,1]$  we have
$$\int_0^1f\Big(\sqrt{{1\over u}-1}\Big)(1-u)^{-3/2}u^{p-1/2}du=0,\qquad \text{ for all } p\ge 1$$
that is, the function $g(u):=f\Big(\sqrt{{1\over u}-1}\Big)(1-u)^{-3/2}u^{1/2}$ has $\int_o^1g(u)u^pdu=0$ for all $p\in\mathbb{N}$, so it must be identically zero, and so must $f$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your rather concise and elegant solution

Comment: @GiannidelFiore You're welcome. Note that it suffices:$f(x)(1+x^2)^{-p_0}$ is integrable for some $p_0$, and  $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)(1+x^2)^{-p_j}dx=0$ for an infinite bounded set  of $p_j\ge p_0$. 

If $p_j\to+\infty$, you can use the Müntz–Szász theorem to get the same conclusion or the existence of a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

The connection between this question and uniqueness sets for holomorphic functions has already been mentioned but I think that it could benefit from a more systematic treatment. Let me begin with Müntz’  result concerning when the span of the sequence $(x^{\lambda_n})$ is dense in $C[0,1]$. If one considers the  holomorphic function $F(z)=\int x^z dx$ then it can be dualised to the question of sets or sequences of uniqueness for bounded analytic functions in  the right half plane.  These are completely understood (e.g. by using a Möbius tranformation to reduce to functions on the unit disc and then Blaschke products). This provides a proof of the Müntz result in the special case where the exponents are real and go to infinity but also in many other cases (convergence to zero, complex exponentials which converge slowly to the imaginary small corrections—-axes).

In the case in question here one uses the function $F(z)=\int f(x)(1+x^2)^{-z} dx$ which is analytic on a suitable region of the plane.  Then sets of uniqueness provide results of this type—-in the case of the original posting the rather crude one of a real interval.