# Functions orthogonal to powers of $1/{\left(1+x^2\right)}$

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions with the following properties:

1. $f(x)$ and ${g(x)}/x$ are bounded;
2. ${g(x)}/{\left(1+x^2\right)}\in L^1\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$;
3. $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)/x^2=1$;

and also
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f(x)}{\left(1+x^2\right)^p}dx=p\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{g(x)}{\left(1+x^2\right)^p}dx$$
for every real number $p\geq1$.

How special is the pair $\left(f,g\right)$?

Comment: Shouldn't you want $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ divided by all powers of $1+x^2$ to be in $L^1$? Or else you should specify how the integrals are defined.

Comment: @WillSawin, I think it follows from boundedness of $f$ and from the condition 2).

Comment: @Gianni del Fiore if you denote $G(x) = \frac{g(x) (1+x^{2})}{-2x}$, and it happens that $G(x)$ is differentiable then $p\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{g(x)}{(1+x^{2})^{p}}dx = -\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{G'(x)}{(1+x^{2})^{p}}dx$. Therefore you can use the solution to your previous question (having the same title) to conclude that $f(x)+G'(x)=0$ is what you are looking for. If you do not have differentiability of $G$ you may run things backwards and conclude something like this $G+\int f =const$ where $\int f$ is antiderivative of $f$. I believe it should not be diffficult to fill out the details.

Comment: first you will have to symmetrize both f and g and then run the argument. otherwise any odd functions satisfy the conditions

Comment: @PaataIvanishvili: I think your idea works even better if we instead integrate by parts on the left-hand side, so write $\int f(1+x^2)^{-p} = p \int F(1+x^2)^{-p-1}$ to conclude that $F/(1+x^2)=g$ (maybe I'm just repeating what you said in the second part of your first comment).

Comment: @ChristianRemling, exactly, this is what I wanted to say. Okay, I will post it as the answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\tilde{f}(x) = f(x)+f(-x)$, and $\tilde{g} (x) = g(x)+g(-x)$, and let $F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \tilde{f}(t)dt$. Then your condition can be rewritten as (after integration by parts in the left hand side) 
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2xF(x)-\tilde{g}(x) (1+x^{2})}{1+x^{2}} (1+x^{2})^{-p}dx =0
$$
for all $p\geq 1$.

Now you can use the same density argument from here [Function orthogonal to powers of $1/\left(1+x^2\right)$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336892/function-orthogonal-to-powers-of-1-left1x2-right)

(notice that $\frac{2xF(x)-\tilde{g}(x) (1+x^{2})}{1+x^{2}} \cdot \frac{1}{1+x^{2}}\in L^{1}([0, \infty))$ to conclude that $\frac{2xF(x)}{1+x^{2}} = \tilde{g}(x)$ on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. In reference to one of your comments, notice that condition 3 prevents $f$ from being an odd function. Each day I get more impressed with the high level of this Q&A site as well as you guys' commitment to help researchers advance in their pursuit to broaden the frontiers of mathematical knowledge.